# Used in various games

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm looking for a phrase. Try to find it!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can take these six grids and

> reorder according to the middle letters: oNe, tWo, thRee, fOUr, fIVe, sIx

giving the patterns

> N
>  U I F
>  A **F** H
>  R E V
>
>  W
>  **A** B M
>  H E L
>  Q Z **C**
>
>  R
>  **E** I A
>  M **S** E
>  S B **O**
>
>  OU
>  **F** O **A**
>  I P L
>  **D** M **I**
>
>  IV
>  **C** A **E**
>  W **I** R
>  **N** V **C**
>
>  I
>  **O** R **G**
>  **N** E **I**
>  **T** X **O**

displaying a relevant phrase per the title and presentation

> **FACES OF A DICE INCOGNITO**

Comment: This is it, well done!